# Handling the browser back button in Spring + Tiles (Java Application)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, tiles

I am developing a Project Management System in Spring + Tiles.

Now I have a project list page where all the project name are listed...
On clicking a Link it will redirect me to its information page(proj info page).
Now in that page I have a link to delete that project. 
After deleting the project I will again be redirected to the project list page.. 
Now the problem is from the project list page If a press the back button of the browser it shows me the project info page that was opened earlier. (It displays the page from the cash memory)

When the browser back button is clicked it does not go again in my controller but renders the page from the cache. 
So writing the code of my controller in try catch block won't help me with my problem.

So can anybody help me how to handle the back button of the browser????

But Before that Please Note: 
1. I don't want to disable the browser back button
2. I don't want to use "no-cache" header (meaning  I want the cache to be maintained)
.. 
So Please help me with the appropriate solution

Comment: If you tell the browser it can cache the page, then it will not call your system at all when back button is clicked. How do you expect it to call your controller?

Comment: `After deleting the project I will again be redirected to the project list page` which hits your controller and the resulting page is cached by the browser. `Now the problem is from the project list page If a press the back button of the browser it shows me the project info page that was opened earlier.` which will be the page rendered by the controller with the project deleted, which is what you want, no?

Comment: Yes. But the back button does not go again to my controller, but renders (from cache) the previously shown proj info page of the of the already deleted proj.